# PostgreSQL -Assign Unique ID to each groups of records, based on a condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, vertica

I am trying to group records of a table, based on a condition, and then asing in a new column a simple integer ID for each group obtained from where the condition is met.

| ID | TMSTP | CAT_TYPE | TELEGRAMMZAEHLER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-05-03 20:52:02 | 32 | 5004 |
| 2 | 2022-05-03 20:51:34 | 32 | 5002 |
| 3 | 2022-05-03 20:51:34 | 32 | 5001 |
| 4 | 2022-05-03 20:51:33 | 32 | 5000 |
| 5 | 2022-05-03 20:41:22 | 32 | 4996 |
| 6 | 2022-05-03 20:41:21 | 32 | 4995 |

I need to assign the same ID to those rows whose TELEGRAMMZAEHLER number is consecutive to the next one (for example, rows 2 and 3 have TZ 5002 and 5001, therefore they are consecutive and should belong to a same Group ID.)

The GRUPPE column would be my desired outcome. Rows 2 to 4 belong together in the same group ID, bur then rows 5 and 6 should have another ID, because the TZ in row 5 is not consecutive from the TZ in row 4.

| ID | TMSTP | CAT_TYPE | TELEGRAMMZAEHLER | GRUPPE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-05-03 20:52:02 | 32 | 5004 | 1 |
| 2 | 2022-05-03 20:51:34 | 32 | 5002 | 2 |
| 3 | 2022-05-03 20:51:34 | 32 | 5001 | 2 |
| 4 | 2022-05-03 20:51:33 | 32 | 5000 | 2 |
| 5 | 2022-05-03 20:41:22 | 32 | 4996 | 3 |
| 6 | 2022-05-03 20:41:21 | 32 | 4995 | 3 |

Any ideas on how can that be achieved on postgreSQL?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `LAG` here along with `SUM` as an analytic function:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, CASE WHEN TELEGRAMMZAEHLER =
                        LAG(TELEGRAMMZAEHLER) OVER (ORDER BY TMSTP DESC) - 1
                   THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS idx
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT ID, TMSTP, CAT_TYPE, TELEGRAMMZAEHLER,
       SUM(idx) OVER (ORDER BY TMSTP DESC) AS GRUPPE
FROM cte
ORDER BY TMSTP DESC;
```

### Demo